# What does 'twentyeleven' does in the Twenty Eleven Wordpress Theme

Tags: php, wordpress, themes, theming

The Twenty eleven theme has a little snippet in almost every part of it, for example the next:

```
<?php

    printf( __( 'Daily Archives: %s', 'twentyeleven' ), '<span>' . get_the_date() . '</span>' );

?>
```

What does this part mean?

```
'twentyeleven'
```

I understand (or think I do) all the rest, but what if i just delete that portion of code, or should I change it for something else?

What is the purpose of `twentyeleven` in the middle of the code?

Comment: If it doesn't mean *anything*, goldarn, what's the point in *anything*?

Comment: You could dig around and figure out what the `__()` function is doing. or you could retain your sanity and dump wordpress into the nearest cesspool.

Comment: @MarcB - Cesspool seems about right.

Comment: That looks like a localization category.

Answer (score 3):

[Function reference: __](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/_2)

### Usage:

```
<?php $translated_text = __( $text, $domain ); ?>
```

The second argument, `$domain`, is the domain from which to fetch the translation.  So the twentyeleven theme has its own translation list for localizing strings.  Ultimately it translates the string `Daily Archives` into whatever language is being used, getting the translation provided by the theme.

I checked and there is a translation file in the twentyeleven theme (in the `languages` directory) but it doesn't actually have any translations in it so it would appear that the twentyeleven theme is English only.

See more about [Translating WordPress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Translating_WordPress) and POT files.

Comment: it is everywhere, its in the footer, almost everywhere in the theme. 

<p><?php _e( 'Apologies, but no results were found for the requested archive. Perhaps searching will help find a related post.', 'twentyeleven' ); ?></p>

and you say it is for the translation?

Comment: Yes, [_e](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/_e) is also a function for translation.  `_e` is the same as `translate()` and `__()`.